# Why Svelte transition (svg path) only works when I add a console.log?

Tags: svelte, svelte-transition

When I use the fade transition on a svg path like this:

```
<svg>
{#if visible}     
<path transition:fade d="M15.24,13.18l-4.77,7.94L236Z" transform="translate(0.24 34.65)"/>
{/if}
<path transition:fade d="2.65-4.41-3.35-4.41-3.35l-1.06-5.47h-3l-5.73,1.59-1.33,1.94-1.67" transform="translate(0.24 34.65)"/>
</svg>
```

Then the animation of fade out works perfectly fine whenever I toggle the boolean value of "**visible**", however, the fade in doesn't work and the path pops out abruptly.

However, if I add a reactive statement like this:
`$: console.log(visible)` then everything works fine.

I have to mention that the variable **visible** is a prop from this component, changed in a parent component and then the child reacts (console log indicates that the variable is changing properly from parent component and correctly received by child).

Comment: Can you recreate this behavior in a REPL? [Here](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world)

Comment: I second JHeth's request. I [cannot reproduce the issue](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a1bf681bb894d5ca22a18dfee4118ec?version=3.49.0).